# Quicksort in scheme

Tags: scheme

please, what is bad in my code ? how can i modify that ?

```
(define pivot (lambda (l)
  (cond ((null? l) 'done)
    ((null? (cdr l)) 'done)
        ((<= (car l) (cadr l)) (pivot (cdr l)))
        (#t (car l)))))

(define (quicksort l)
 (let ((piv (pivot l)))
   (if (equal? piv 'done) l
     (let ((parts (partition piv l () ())))
       (append (quicksort (car parts)) 
               (quicksort (cadr parts)))))))
```

Comment: You could fix the formatting!

Comment: Don't replace the question with "aaaaaaa", use the comments to provide further information if needed

Answer (score 3):

Some Scheme interpreters define a `partition` procedure, but it receives a different set of parameters, so I'm assuming that you defined your own version. The implementation of `quicksort` shown in the question *might* work, but the `partition` procedure is almost certainly wrong. It's hard to tell without the code...